# convert inputs to selects

Tags: jquery, input, html-select

I'm looking to convert inputs to selects using Jquery, while taking the value form the input and using it as the selected option. But I've only got half way there so far in the below code. Can anyone see where its going wrong? Or maybe suggest an alternative method.

HTML

```
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input01" value="1" name="input01"/></div>
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input02" value="4" name="input02"/></div>
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input03" value="2" name="input03"/></div>
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input04" value="1" name="input04"/></div>
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input05" value="4" name="input05"/></div>
```

JS

```
$(".inputDiv input[type=text]").each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(qty + " is a Number");
    alert(currentId + " is a ID");
    $(this).replaceWith('<select id="' + currentId + '" name="" class="NewSelect">' +
          '<option value="1">1</option>' +
          '<option value="2">2</option>' +
          '<option value="3">3</option>' +
          '<option value="4">4</option>' +
          '<option value="5">5</option>' +
        '</select>');

        $("option[value=" +this.qty+ "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Comment: id's have to be unique in the dom

Comment: thanks that was accidently copy pasted, edited example code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(".inputDiv input[type=text]").each(function() {
        var qty = this.value;
        var currentId = this.id;
        var selectbox = $('<select id="'+currentId+'><option value="-1"></select>');
        $(this).replaceWith(selectbox);
        for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = i;
            $(option).text(i);
            if(i==qty) option.setAttribute('selected','selected');
            selectbox.append($(option));

        }

    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4pQTb/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().replaceWith('<option id=' + this.id + ' value='+ this.value + ' name=' + this.name + ">" + this.value +"</option>")
})        
$('option').wrapAll('</select>')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xKZyF/)

Answer (score 0):

do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/albertjan/heVc6/3/

In the DOM: make the id's unique

```
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input01" value="1" name="input01"/></div>
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input02" value="4" name="input01"/></div>
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input03" value="2" name="input01"/></div>
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input04" value="1" name="input01"/></div>
<div class="inputDiv"><input type="text" id="input05" value="4" name="input01"/></div>​
```

In javascript:

```
$(".inputDiv input[type=text]").each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(qty + " is a Number");
    alert(currentId + " is a ID");
    $(this).replaceWith('<select id="' + currentId + '" name="" class="NewSelect">' +
          '<option value="1">1</option>' +
          '<option value="2">2</option>' +
          '<option value="3">3</option>' +
          '<option value="4">4</option>' +
          '<option value="5">5</option>' +
          '</select>');

  //this qty instead of this.qty
  //search for an option within the current div.
  $("#" + currentId + " option[value=" + qty + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, but i needed the inputs to become select boxes @rsplak had the right idea

Comment: have you even looked at the jsfiddle I posted ?? hehe

Comment: yep, ic moo tools was the default loader, changed it to jquery to see the result. Though option isn't being selected. Cheers